# Spark UI is showing active jobs that never finish. Is this normal?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark application running on EMR. Within minutes of my application starting, jobs start piling that never seem to finish.
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDEdw.png)
Also, the active jobs count just keeps increasing. I looked at the executors tab. The number of active tasks per executor is increasing.
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrWN6.png)
What could be the problem?

I tried increasing the number of executors, and giving more memory per executor.

Comment: Please post your code with spark parameters you used for the job. It is highly likely because of the data getting split in your code.